# Iterative equation across rows in a for loop only stores last value

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a dataset, gl, and I want to produce a second data set, gl2,  with an equation that draws from gl. However, it only stores the last value from my loop.

gl:

```
CaseID  Trait   RMF     RMFE    ZM      ZME     ZF      ZFE     avG     errG
171     Lrs     -0.85   0.6     0.92    0.022   0.77    0.018   0.043  0.051
172     Hll     0.4     0.14    171.8   0.680   172.5   0.5333  22.8    3.6
173     W       0.42    0.09    19.7    0.382   18.7    0.2125  0.79    0.4
174     Fec     0.27    0.13    1.63    0.036   0.92    0.034   0.039  0.009
201     ConPG   -0.95   0.42    0.00018 8.65E-5 0.0008  6.61E-5 7.93    7.06
206     Lrs     -0.48   0.44    0.98    0.129   2.27    0.118   61.07  58.94
131     PWm1    0.4     0.48    191     1.048   131     0.733   157     75
132     PWm2    0.53    0.06    198     0.650   135     0.396   263     92
133     PWm3    0.59    0.22    157     0.670   109     0.391   195     195
```

Code:

```
draws <- 10^6
gl2 <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=9, ncol=1))
gl2$CaseID <- gl$CaseID
gl2$Trait <- gl$Trait

for (i in nrow(gl)){
  G <- rnorm(draws, gl$avG[i], gl$errG[i])
  zm <- rnorm(draws, gl$ZM[i], gl$ZME[i])
  zf <- rnorm(draws, gl$ZF[i], gl$ZFE[i])
  rmf <- rnorm(draws, gl$RMF[i], gl$RMFE[i])

  load <- (zm + zf)/(8*G + rmf)
  mload <- mean(load)

  gl2[i,1] <- c(mload)
}
```

The output, which I hoped to be a new column for gl2 with the result of the equation (mload) as it runs through each row, is instead a single value in the last row of column 1. 
I know this is not efficient code, but this is how I understand it. I have spent days playing with it and have found no solution, nor do I understand why it isn't working. 
Thanks.

Comment: Do `for (i in 1:nrow(gl))`, as is now, `i` only takes one value: the number of rows in `gl`

Comment: I knew it would be simple... thank you!!